# Can I change the terminal's PS1 only when working in certain directories/sub-directories?

Tags: terminal, directory, ps1

I would like to change PS1, but only if I am working in a particular directory. Is this possible, and how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. I have used `PROMPT_COMMAND` to make this possible. This function is executed before any other command and is here where you can compare your current directory and make whatever you need. As you can see I am only checking the last path of the directory and just showing the apple logo if matches.

```
function __get_dir {
    DIR=$(basename `pwd`)
    if [[ $DIR == "desiredDir" ]]
    then
    LOGO=" "
    else
    LOGO=""
    fi
}

PROMPT_COMMAND='__get_dir'

PS1="\W \u\[\033[0;33m\]\$(parse_git_branch_and_add_brackets) \$LOGO\[\033[0m\]\$ "
```